# java GridLayout component size

Tags: java, swing, layout, grid, grid-layout

I want to make a `JPanel` (with `GridLayout`) that contains a grid of custom components. All is ok, but I have problem with the components size. The components size each time grows or diminishes so the total dimension of all the components fills the `JPanel`'s region. I want the internal components have a standard size, and if the total dimension of all components is smaller than `JPanel`'s dimension then leave it empty, or if the total dimension is bigger than the `JPanel`'s region then use the scrollpane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use GridBagLayout instead. Or you can try to override the GridLayout's methods

```
public void layoutContainer(Container parent)
public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent)
public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try and I'll be back with feedback!

Comment: I override the three methods. In the last two I return the wanted dimension for child components, and in the first I must create and container object with specific dimensions and passed to parent layoutContainer method? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I get it to work with gridbaglayout, but now try with weights and empty components to place the grid at top left corner of the panel

Comment: All ok now  with using gridbaglayout!! thank you,!                  So gridbaglayout saves me again!

Comment: GridLayout is rather simple so if we need something not usual GridBagLayout is #1 to try.